# Estimate on Euclidean norm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

Let $A = \mathrm{diag}(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ with $a_1>a_2\geq \dots \geq a_n\geq -a_1$. Let $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ be a vector with $\sum_{j=1}^n x_j = 0$. Prove that $\|Ax\|_2 \leq \max\{|a_2|, |a_{n}|\}\, \|x\|_2$. I do not see how to get rid of the $a_1$ to prove this estimate. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true.

For $A = \mathrm{diag}(1,0,...,0)$ and $x =(1,-1, 0, 0, ..., 0)^T$, you have
$$Ax = (1,0, 0, 0, ..., 0)^T$$

so $||Ax||_2 \neq 0$, but $\max \lbrace |a_2|, |a_n| \rbrace = 0$.